# OpenLayers 3 create bounding extent which includes a few points

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm working with openlayer3 in my ionic application and am stucked with the problem with creating a bounding extent to get a few points in the viewport.

My code looks like this:

```
var centerView = ol.proj.transform([lng, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lng, lat], 'EPSG:4326',   'EPSG:3857')),
  name: 'Ziel'
});

var destLoc = [6.18581,50.88093];
var currentLoc = [-122.29925626,37.47836852];

var ext = ol.extent.boundingExtent([destLoc,currentLoc]);
map.getView().fit(ext,map.getSize());
```

But this code gives me a extent of the currentLoc and not the whole extent which includes both points.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ext seems right to me, what do you get? [-122.29925626, 37.47836852, 6.18581, 50.88093] Is your view defined in EPSG:4326 ?

Comment: I've editied the posting. I'm very very new in openlayers so I just copy pasted the view call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was answered here already: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179051/openlayers-3-create-bounding-extent-which-includes-two-points:

```
map.getView().fit(
    ol.proj.transformExtent(ext, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    map.getSize());
```